# align two Images with extrinsic and intrinsic matrix

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera, camera-calibration, calibration

I have a simple problem, but still it confuses me somehow.

I have two cameras. One is closer to an object than the other one. I have both intrinsic matrices from each camera, as well as the distortion vectors(which are 0). I already calculated the extrinsic matrix between both cameras.
Now I want to transform the image from the camera, which is further away, into the same coordinates as the closer image. Such that the images are aligned, and have the same size.

Does anyone know how I can do this? By using the intrinsic an extrinsic matrices?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In theory: For each ray from.camera center through the pixel plane, find the ray of the other camera that intersects (or passes closest to) it.

Comment: their optical centers don't coincide so you can't establish such a mapping in general. at best, you can calculate a plane-to-plane mapping, but anything out-of-plane will be distorted.

Comment: @Micka : Many rays can intersect. How can we choose the one?
There is no good way, I think.

Comment: @fana for every picel choose the intersection with closest shortest distance to the camera position.

Comment: @Micka : Sorry, I can not understand... When Camera_A is behind Camera_B, ray from Camera_A to the point P intersects the outermost ray from Camera_B. (where, the point P was observed by both cameras)
In this case, will the selected ray (from Camera_B) always correspond to the outer pixels of Camera_B's image...?

Comment: I think this is a stereo view problem.
Only pixels which can be estimated their 3D location from 2 views can be warped.
Of caurse, generaly, result of such method will be very very sparse.
Some kind of interpolation way may be able to be considered, but it would be difficult to achieve enough accuracy.

Comment: Sorry, I think my comment was wrong. With the ray intersections will could find candidates, but the actual correspondence depends on the scene content and there you will need some kind of matching score. Have a look at general epipolar geometry. Maybe you'll find some papers which address your problem.